# Display image at 100% width or as big as fits in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I display an image so that its width is the original image width or 100% of the browser width, whichever is smaller (I want to show as much of the image as possible without horizontal scrolling).

Is this possible with CSS, or do I need to play around with javascript?

Comment: @emmanuel that does not work as it makes the image always fit to the width, I NEVER want the image to be bigger than its real resolution.

Comment: Javascript. You can't add conditions to css selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [<kbd>jsFiddle.net Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/dL9cf9tf/)

html:

```
<img src="http://gypsypixiepirate.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Rumpus-party.jpg" class="className" />
```

css:

```
.className {
    max-width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution: I adjusted your fiddle to have a smaller image to demonstrate the magic (not stretching an image beyond its original size). -- [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/vkph322e/)

Comment: Also, here is a version that keeps the image within the document flow by positioning it within a relatively positioned parent container: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/vkph322e/1/)